# How to add namespace reference

Tags: asp.net

How to add namespace to a web form present in a folder. e.g folder name is *suppliers* and application name is *inventorysystem*.

Now how to refer to a webform `abc.aspx` by adding a reference to namespace?

Comment: you want to refer to abc from elsewhere right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `inventorysystem.suppliers.abc` not work?

If you click on an unresolved name in VS you'll get a little dash underneath, you can hover over it (or with your cursor on it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>) and VS will find the right namespace if it is references.

Comment: thanks gideon, i dont know why yesterday it was not working, now it is working. thx for your answer.